# Create a plot given lat lon coordinates and wind direction

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I would like to create a plot given lat lon coordinates and wind direction.

So basically an arrow head should display the direction (column:dd) and should be placed at coordinates given by lat lon.

Currently this is my result:

[image]

The arrows are very long and im not sure if those are placed correctly.
The overall image should have the following bbox coordinates:

```
 nw <- c(2.00348,55.08617)
 se <- c(15.79388, 46.99609)
```

Within this plot area I would like to place the arrows accourding to the lat lon coordinates and wind direction given by dd column.

This is my approach:

```
wind_data<-structure(list(lat = c(54.8795643952007, 54.8795643952007, 54.8795643952007, 
54.8795643952007, 54.8795643952007, 54.8795643952007), lon = c(9.18175071980108, 
9.19724595932033, 9.21274049124152, 9.25921982682543, 9.27471151376548, 
9.29020248581541), dd = c(202, 202, 202, 202, 203, 203), ff = c(8.75, 
8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.23, 8.23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(wind_data, 
       aes(x = wind_data$lon , 
           y = wind_data$lat, 
           fill = dd, 
           angle = dd, 
           radius = scales::rescale(dd, c(.2, .8)))) +
  geom_raster() +
  geom_spoke(arrow = arrow(length = unit(.05, 'inches'))) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") + 
  coord_equal(expand = 0) + 
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom', 
        legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
ggplot(wind_data, aes(x = lon, y = lat)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = lon + 0.08, yend = lat + 0.08),
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm")), size = 0.25)   # Make the line segments 0.25 mm thick
```